# Detectar en PHP(exif_read_data) la orientación de la foto obtenida con iPhone

Tags: php, iphone

Estoy con un proyecto donde el objetivo es guardar/procesar las imágenes obtenidas con el móvil: Imágenes que capturadas en el móvil ocupan entorno a 2MB(o más) y hay que guardarlas con un tamaño de 50kb aproximadamente. Asumiendo la pérdida de calidad por esta disminución de tamaño.

Uno de los inconvenientes que existen es la detección de la orientación de la imagen, para guardarla con la orientación correcta.

Para resolver esta situación estoy haciendo uso de la librería exif_read_data, pero ocurre que para imágenes obtenidas con un iPhone esta librería devuelve el siguiente error:

```
exif_read_data(phpXSi4c5): Illegal IFD size
```

Donde el literal `phpXSi4c5` es el nombre que le da el Sistema al fichero enviado al servidor desde un campo tipo file en un formulario html.

De momento lo he resuelto con las siguientes instrucciones:

```
                try {
                    $exif = exif_read_data($_FILES['fotoElemento']['tmp_name']);
                }
                catch (Exception $exp) {
                    $exif = false;
                }
                if($exif) { ... }
```

Ahora bien, tras realizar el ajuste anterior, ya no se produce el error indicado pero cuando subo imágenes capturadas con un iPhone se guardan sin la orientación correcta: Es decir las imágenes giradas 90 grados.

Esto tiene sentido porque la imagen no ha sido procesada, ya que (atendiendo al código indicado anteriormente) $efix es falso.

Las preguntas son:

1. ¿Alguna recomendación para resolver esta situación y guardar con la
   orientación correcta imágenes capturadas desde un iPhone?
2. ¿Recomiendan otras librerías que resuelvan esta situación?

La versión de PHP que estoy utilizando en el servidor es la 5.6.33

Comment: Pero aquí el problema es que no estás pudiendo leer los datos exif de las fotos, eso que haces con el try catch no es más que un hack; dudo mucho que el dato de la orientación no esté incluído en las fotos tomadas con iPhone (de hecho si en el móvil las ves con la orientación correcta, es porque el dato está), pero al no poder leer los datos exif obviamente no podrás saber la orientación.

Comment: El origen de esta situación viene dado por el hecho de que los dispositivos iPhone utilizan el formato HEIC, y cunado la imagen sale del dispositivo iPhone lo hace en formato jpg.

Como solución inmediata lo que se me a ocurrido es que aquellas imágenes que no tengan metainformación EXIF, entonces las proceso por medio las propiedades width y height del propio fichero de la imagen.

Comment: Recordar que en los dispositivos iPhone utilizan el formato HEIC, y al salir del dispositivo(enviar por correo, subir a internet, etc...) iPhone lo hace en formato jpg.

Para las  imágenes que no tengan metainformación EXIF, entonces las proceso por medio las propiedades width y height del propio fichero de la imagen. Y después utilizo en php el "imagerotate".

$imagen = $_FILES['fotoElemento']['tmp_name'];
$info_imagen = getimagesize($imagen);
$alto = $info_imagen[1];
$ancho = $info_imagen[0];

Otra posible solución pasa por hacer uso de las librerías ImageMagick.

Saludos.